# Stata - Add Prefix to Variable Values

Tags: string, loops, latex, stata

I have many variables.  For brevity, assume I have two: `Gender` and `Meal`. In Stata, I am using `tabout`, a package that allows one to produce `.tex` based on Stata results that can be opened as tables in LaTeX.

In order to create a customized output with a little spacing before the variable labels, I want to assign a prefix, `\hspace{0.3cm}`, to the beginning of all of the values (not labels) of each variable.  How can I do this automatically with a loop instead of manually doing this?

Let's say I start out with this:

```
label def gen 0 "Male" 1 "Female", modify
label value Gender gen

label def me 0 "Lunch" 1 "Dinner", modify
label value Meal me
```

I want to have a loop that will automatically add the prefix to the individual values of `Gender` and `Meal`.  The end result would be the same as if I had originally done:

```
label def gen 0 "\hspace{0.3cm}Male" 1 "\hspace{0.3cm}Female", modify
label value Gender gen

label def me 0 "\hspace{0.3cm}Lunch" 1 "\hspace{0.3cm}Dinner", modify
label value Meal me
```

Note that code (from http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/) to do a similar thing for variable labels (and NOT values) is as follows:

```
foreach v of varlist * {
    label variable `v' `"\hspace{0.1cm} `: variable label `v''"'
    }
```

Comment: How are you creating the LaTeX code? Maybe programs in Stata that do such a thing, will allow you to set that kind of formatting without tampering with the labels.

Comment: See my comment on Nick Cox's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that produces the strings you want. I leave to you defining the new value labels and assigning to the variables. Let us know if it's useful.

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example -----

label def gen 0 "Male" 1 "Female", modify
*label value Gender gen

label def meal 0 "Lunch" 1 "Dinner", modify
*label value Meal me

*----- what you want -----

label dir
local rnames `=r(names)'

foreach labname of local rnames {

    quietly label list `labname'
    local myname

    forvalues i = 0/`r(max)' {

        local name : label `labname' `i', strict
        local newname \hspace{0.3cm}`name'

        local myname `myname' `newname'

    }

    display "`myname'"

}
```

You can make it a bit shorter, but it's all very "explicit".

`help label` and `help extended_fcn` are a must-read.

(I still insist that a solution within `tabout` is **maybe** possible; but I can't be sure.)

### Edit

The following is more general, has better form and is a complete example. *Extended macro functions* are still the basis for the code.

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example database -----

sysuse voter

*----- what you want -----

foreach var of varlist _all {

    local cnewname

    quietly labellist `var'

    if  "`r(lblname)'" != "" {
        *disp "`var'"

        forvalues i = 1/`r(`r(lblname)'_k)' { 

            local val : word `i' of `r(values)'
            local labval : word `i' of `r(labels)'

            local newname `val' "\hspace{0.3cm}`labval'"
            local cnewname `cnewname' `newname'

        } // forvalues

    label define newlbl`var' `cnewname'
    label value `var' newlbl`var'

    } // if

} // foreach


labellist
```

I define new value labels and re-associate with corresponding variables. You can try replacing or whatever fits your needs.

Comment: For reference, I also found that `~` can be a shorter replacement that also works to add white space in `LaTeX`.

Answer (score 2):

Stata doesn't understand TeX or LaTeX, at least not like this.

You could just prefix with space(s), but often Stata would just ignore them any way.

A bizarre trick I've used occasionally is to use `char(160)` as a pad which looks like a space but won't be trimmed.

```
length(trim("`=char(160)'"))
```

is reported as 1, i.e. `char(160)` is not trimmed. To check that `char(160)` is invisible on your machine,

```
di char(160)
```

But how this works surely depends on your TeX/LaTeX code and how it treats that character.

Comment: I am using tabout in order to generate a .tex file to produce a table that can be opened later in LaTeX.  In other words, I don't care about what it looks like in Stata, just LaTeX.  I want to have the variable values indented as in http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/  This website provides code of how to do what I want with the exception that he adds space in front of the variable labels and not the variable values.  He uses est, so it is a bit different.

Comment: `foreach v of varlist * {
 label variable `v' `"\hspace{0.1cm} `: variable label `v''"'
 }`

Comment: The above code (when not squished as it is here) is the right idea, but does it for the variable label and not the variable values.  This code is from the aforementioned website.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to ask the question you really have. 1. You didn't mention `tabout`, but that seems central to what you are doing. (Good idea to document its provenance too.) 2. You showed code on value labels, but you now comment on **variable** labels, so what you want is not very clear. In principle, you could prefix string values too, but not numeric values.

Comment: Good points.  I made the edits.  Hopefully everything is in better order now.  Sorry for the confusion.